# Using nx option when doing zadd in redis-py (redis ver 2.8.4)

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I'm using redis 2.8.4 in a python project of mine. In a particular sorted set, I want to `zadd` with the `nx` option. The `nx` option isn't documented in [redis-py](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) docs, and according [to the docs](https://redis.io/commands/zadd), it only works with redis 3.0.2 or greater.

So what's an alternative pattern I can follow to simulate the `nx` option when doing `zadd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution in [github issue](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/issues/649#issuecomment-346997655):

```
redis.execute_command('ZADD', set_name, 'NX', score, key)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient pattern that comes to my mind is using using `zscore` (or `zrank`) to test for existence. If value exists, do nothing, otherwise, `zadd` the relevant value.

Comment: `ZSCORE` is constant time so would be more efficient than `ZRANK`, whose time depends on the size of the set.

Comment: Helpful comment.